# Cannot call method in decimal SQL Server error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Here is my query with left join and I am automatically developing credit debit and balance.

Perhaps I am lacking upon column. I used `gl_drcr` as main column and split it by query into credit and debit but I am unable to get value of balance. I have column of amount also, where I can store amount values.

Can you help me to sort out where my fault is in this query?

My stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_getDataML]
    (@gl_acid int, @userid int)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY gLedeger.PK_id) AS sno,
        CASE 
           WHEN master.ma_accname IS NULL THEN '' 
           ELSE ma_accname 
        END AS AccName, 
        gLedeger.gl_date AS date, gLedeger.gl_narration AS Narration, 
        gLedeger.gl_drcr as DRCR,
        CASE
           WHEN gLedeger.gl_drcr > 0 THEN ABS(gLedeger.gl_drcr) 
           ELSE 0.00 
        END AS debit,
        CASE 
           WHEN gLedeger.gl_drcr < 0 THEN ABS(gLedeger.gl_drcr) 
           ELSE 0.00 
        END AS credit,
        SUM(COALESCE(gLedeger.gl_drcr.credit, 0) - COALESCE(gLedeger.gl_drcr.debit, 0)) AS Balance  
    FROM 
        gLedeger   
    LEFT JOIN 
        master ON gLedeger.GL_ACID = master.PK_ID 
    LEFT JOIN
        registration r ON master.userId = @userid
    WHERE 
        gLedeger.GL_ACID = @gl_acid
        /*and LEFT(gLedeger.gl_voucher,2)=@voucher*/
    ORDER BY 
        gLedeger.gl_date
END
```

Comment: make sure your code is formatted as code for improved legibility

Comment: You have aggregate function in your query but not used GROUP by clause

Comment: i am just beginner in coding can you tell me how  can i use group in above query????

Answer (score 0):

i got this solution as follows:-

ALTER procedure [dbo].[fulltest]
(
  @gl_acid int,
  @userid int
  )
  as 
  begin

SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by gLedeger.PK_id) as sno,case when master.ma_accname is null then '' else ma_accname end as AccName,gLedeger.gl_date as date,gLedeger.gl_narration  as Narration,gLedeger.gl_drcr as DRCR,
    case when gLedeger.gl_drcr > 0 then abs(gLedeger.gl_drcr) else 0.00 end as debit,
    case when gLedeger.GL_DRCR   < 0 then abs(gLedeger.gl_drcr) else 0.00 end as credit,
SUM(gLedeger.gl_drcr) OVER(ORDER BY gledeger.pk_ID ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS    Balance
    FROM gLedeger   LEFT JOIN master ON 
    gLedeger.GL_ACID = master.PK_ID left join registration r on master.userId=@userid
    WHERE gLedeger.GL_ACID = @gl_acid
    /*and LEFT(gLedeger.gl_voucher,2)=@voucher*/

```
ORDER BY gLedeger.gl_date

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SUM(COALESCE(gLedeger.gl_drcr.credit, 0) - COALESCE(gLedeger.gl_drcr.debit, 0)) AS Balance
```

You can't use dot after field name in sql. Because the format of Selecting fields is

> SERVER.DATABASE.SCHEMA.FIELDNAME